# Android associate html tag to xml style

Tags: android, html, xml, parsing

I am working on a cross platform application for a school for my internship, teachers can write courses and everything is stored in html in a database.

I am doing the Android application and will perform a request to the API we created, so now I am getting an html document, is there any good practices about converting

```
title
```

to some xml predefined style ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with http://jsoup.org/

Also you can use `myTextView.setText( Html.fromHtml("<h2>Your html string</h2>") );`